# Cant make memory work with ConversationalRetrievalChain in Langchain

Tags: python, streamlit, langchain, pinecone

I have simple txt file indexed in pine cone, and question answering works perfectly fine without memory.

When I add ConversationBufferMemory and ConversationalRetrievalChain using session state the 2nd question is not taking into account the previous conversation.

1st Question: Who is John Doe?
He is a male, 70 years old, etc,etc
2nd Question. How old is he?
To who are you referring to?

But chat history looks like this:
[image: langchain]

MY code looks like this, what am I missing?

```
import streamlit as st
import openai
import os
import pinecone
import streamlit as st

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain.chat_models import AzureChatOpenAI
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import Pinecone
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_chat import message
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import ConversationChain
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
#load environment variables
load_dotenv()

OPENAI_API_KEY = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_ENDPOINT = os.getenv("OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_ENDPOINT")
OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME = os.getenv("OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME")
OPENAI_MODEL_NAME = os.getenv("OPENAI_MODEL_NAME")
OPENAI_EMBEDDING_DEPLOYMENT_NAME = os.getenv("OPENAI_EMBEDDING_DEPLOYMENT_NAME")
OPENAI_EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME = os.getenv("OPENAI_EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME")
OPENAI_API_VERSION = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_VERSION")
OPENAI_API_TYPE = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_TYPE")

#pinecone
PINECONE_API_KEY =  os.getenv("PINECONE_API_KEY")
PINECONE_ENV = os.getenv("PINECONE_ENV")

#init Azure OpenAI
openai.api_type = OPENAI_API_TYPE
openai.api_version = OPENAI_API_VERSION
openai.api_base = OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_ENDPOINT
openai.api_key = OPENAI_API_KEY

st.set_page_config(
    page_title="Streamlit Chat - Demo",
    page_icon=":robot:"
)

chat_history = []

def get_text():
    input_text = st.text_input("You: ","Who is John Doe?", key="input")
    return input_text 

def query(payload, chain,query,chat_history ):   
    result = chain({"question": query, "chat_history": chat_history})
    chat_history.append((query, result["answer"]))
    thisdict = {
        "generated_text": result['answer']
    }
    return thisdict, chat_history


def main():
    st.title('Scenario 2: Question Aswering on documents with langchain, pinecone and openai')
    st.markdown(
        """
        This scenario shows how to chat wih a txt file which was indexed in pinecone.
        """
    )

    pinecone.init(
        api_key=PINECONE_API_KEY,  # find at app.pinecone.io
        environment=PINECONE_ENV  # next to api key in console
    )
        
    if 'generated' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state['generated'] = []

    if 'past' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state['past'] = []

    if 'chat_history' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state['chat_history'] = []


    index_name = "default"
    embed = OpenAIEmbeddings(deployment=OPENAI_EMBEDDING_DEPLOYMENT_NAME, model=OPENAI_EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME, chunk_size=1)
    retriever = Pinecone.from_existing_index(index_name, embed)
    user_input = get_text()

    llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
        openai_api_base=OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_ENDPOINT,
        openai_api_version=OPENAI_API_VERSION ,
        deployment_name=OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME,
        openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY,
        openai_api_type = OPENAI_API_TYPE ,
        model_name=OPENAI_MODEL_NAME,
        temperature=0)
    
   
    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)
    chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(llm, retriever.as_retriever(), memory=memory)

    if user_input:
        output, chat_history = query({
            "inputs": {
                "past_user_inputs": st.session_state.past,
                "generated_responses": st.session_state.generated,
                "text": user_input,
            },"parameters": {"repetition_penalty": 1.33}
        },
        chain=chain,
        query=user_input,
        chat_history=st.session_state["chat_history"])
        
        st.session_state.past.append(user_input)
        st.session_state.generated.append(output["generated_text"])
        st.session_state.chat_history.append(chat_history)
      
    
    if st.session_state['generated']:
        for i in range(len(st.session_state['generated'])-1, -1, -1):
            message(st.session_state["generated"][i], key=str(i))
            message(st.session_state['past'][i], is_user=True, key=str(i) + '_user')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same issue.

Try to put your chain inside the st.state_session

e.g.

```
if 'chain' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['chain'] = chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(llm, retriever.as_retriever(), memory=memory)
```

And then use it with:

```
st.session_state.chain.query()
```

Source: https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain-streamlit-template/pull/1/commits/224a1f5a46412c6395a7f2f35931386a5c4b3710#diff-b10564ab7d2c520cdd0243874879fb0a782862c3c902ab535faabe57d5a505e1

*Edit: added the correct solution*

Comment: do you want to connect via chat somehow?

Comment: look at my edited post. this should mitigate your problem. but if i can reach you on some channel, i'm happy to chat.

Comment: if you use discord I am available here:https://discordapp.com/channels/@me/Luis%20Valencia#3421/